# How to add username to the filterset_fields in views Django Rest Framework where the user is the foreign key of the model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have below model in my `models.py` which has the django `User` model as the foreign key and I want to add `username` into the `filterset_fields` in my `views` in order to filter the user employment by `username` instead of user id. Any help would be great! Thank you!

```
class UserEmployment(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employment')
    position = models.TextField(blank=True)
    company = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    currently_work = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Serializer class,

```
class UserEmploymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserEmployment
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'position', 'company', 'start_year', 'end_year', 'currently_work']
```

View class,

```
class UserEmploymentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = UserEmployment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserEmploymentSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['user'] # I want this to be 'username' in order to filter employment list by username
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filterset_class attr.

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework
class UserEmploymentFilter(rest_framework.FilterSet):
    username = rest_framework.CharFilter(field_name='user__username', lookup_expr='iexact')

    class Meta:
        fields = ("username",)
        model = UserEmployment
```

And your view should be like this

```py
class UserEmploymentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = UserEmployment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserEmploymentSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = UserEmploymentFilter
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

After that you can search with `?username=foo`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! I also tried overriding get_queryset() method and it also works fine. Which way is better as you think?

Comment: In my opinion, filterset-class is better than override queryset since your view won't swell up

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score -1):

This also works fine,

```
class UserEmploymentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = UserEmployment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserEmploymentSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get_queryset(self):
    
        queryset = UserEmployment.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user__username=username)
        return queryset
```

Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters